# Convert a Visual Studion Deployment project to Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I have a software I have inherited to maintain. It was written using C# in Visual Studio 2008, and the deployment is done from a VS2008 Deployment project.
I would like to start by converting the setup from the deployment project to and Inno Setup script, but I am not familiar with these deployment projects. Does anyone know of a tool to do this conversion?
Alternatively, is the format and syntax of these files easy to filter to get the installation instructions?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Inno uses a text file format (vaguely similar to ini files). I assume the deployment project file is XML based so it should be possible to automate, but I don't know of any existing tools to do it for you.